# Cancel one file to upload jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `id="cancel_upload"` I want to delete one file in the queue to upload with jQuery, is there a way to do this? this is my code:

```
$("#files").on("change", function() {
  var fp = $("#files");
  var lg = fp[0].files.length;
  var items = fp[0].files;
  var fragment = "";

  if (lg > 4) {
    alert('Upload maksimal 4 file!');
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#list_file").show();
    for (var i = 0; i < lg; i++) {
      var fileName = items[i].name;
      var fileSize = items[i].size;

      fragment +=  '<div class="item">' + '<a class="ui label">' + "(" + formatFileSize(fileSize) + ") " + fileName + '<i class="delete icon" id="cancel_upload"></i>' + "</a>" + "</div>" + "<br>";
    }

    $("#list_file").append(fragment);
    $("#files").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$("cancel_upload").on('click', function() {
  fileName.abort();
});
```

Comment: You won't be able to access `fileName` variable as the scope of variable is different.

Comment: @Shiladitya So, what should I do?

Comment: How are you uploading the files, any AJAX call?

Comment: Cancelling method is accessable by id the change the method `$("#cancel_upload").on('click', function() {
  fileName.abort();
});` You forgot to add `#`

Comment: @Shiladitya yes I see the problem

Comment: Pretty sure a string (`fileName`) doesn't have an `abort()` method... Also, you can't have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: @Shiladitya but still not working

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, just thought of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```js
var ajaxCalll;

$("#files").on("change", function() {
  var fp = $("#files");
  var lg = fp[0].files.length;
  var items = fp[0].files;
  var fragment = "";

  if (lg > 4) {
    alert('Upload maksimal 4 file!');
    return false;
  } else {
    $("#list_file").show();
    for (var i = 0; i < lg; i++) {
      var fileName = items[i].name;
      var fileSize = items[i].size;

      fragment +=  '<div class="item">' + '<a class="ui label">' + "(" + formatFileSize(fileSize) + ") " + fileName + '<i class="delete icon" id="cancel_upload"></i>' + "</a>" + "</div>" + "<br>";
    }

    $("#list_file").append(fragment);
    $("#files").prop('disabled', true);
    
    // assign AJAX Call to ajaxCalll variable
  }
});

$("#cancel_upload").on('click', function() {
  ajaxCalll.abort();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Adi Assign you AJAX method to `ajaxCalll` variable, that will help you abort you ajax call as well.